# Discord.py message.reaction embed

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to do that my bot reacts to a embed that I send and it doesn't work.

The code is that:

```
ruleta_image = discord.Embed(title="RULETA️", description="Hola", colour=discord.Colour.gold())
ruleta_image.set_image(url="https://iosmac.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/juegos-de-apuestas-portada.jpg")
first_run = True<
await si.send(embed=ruleta_image)
while True:
    if first_run:
        first_run = False
        reactmoji = ["", "", "⚫", ""]

        for react in reactmoji:
            await message.add_reaction(react)
```

The problem is that:

```
    await message.add_reaction(react)
NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states pretty clear that didn't define `message`, to define it

```py
message = await si.send(embed=ruleta_image)
```